# Display image from Seperate Drive in html code

Tags: html

I am building a web application and there is a shared drive on our server that all the pictures are on. I want to be able to access that drive and its folders so that I can display images inside of them. This is so that we can easily add and remove pictures from the folder outside of the app if need be. However I cant get the file path to link to the folder.

This is what I'm using based on what i have read online

```
<img src="file:///C:/pictures/deere.jpg">
```

but this is not doing anything. Any Ideas?

Comment: if you go to this route what you get? `file:///C:/pictures/deere.jpg`

Comment: It opens up the picture in windows photo viewer

Comment: ok and you can create a new folder inside the application like `/pictures` and store there the images?

Comment: no the drive is not big enough and the images that i want are on a different drive. The Z drive to specific. That folder is shared thought the comapany and inside it there is a folder called TractorProfiles. I get the file path and save that into a mysql database and then i can query the database and display all the images inside the path that has been saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the only way that I was able to get it to work the way I wanted was that I created a symbolic link to my application folder and then I was able to get it to work between drives